# How to find functions/operators/methods in JS files quickly and easily

Tags: javascript, oop, extjs

I'm looking for an app or a command line tool that can help me quickly find a defined function in a file. The file in question here is the EXT-debug.js file. I want to override some methods(in this case onRender) however I need to figure out the signature of said functions.

I've yet to try Eclipse or Aptana; I'm looking for a more lightweight solution.

Comment: Cmd+F or Ctrl+F, type "function blah", [Return] or [Enter] not doing it for you?  But you probably really want TextMate, Vim, or Emacs.

Comment: `grep "function onRender" EXT-debug.js` ? Very lightweight....

Comment: It's not always super-easy to determine the "signature" of a Javascript function; to some extent, Javascript functions don't really even have a "signature" in the more solid sense of methods in a strongly-typed language.  You have to actually interpret the code to figure out what a particular argument may mean.

Comment: If you have name of the function, you can "override" it by having function with the same name in the very bottom of the page - the "signature" aka list of arguments is not relevant as JS has no function overloading.

Answer (score 1):

I use agent ransack.  It's able to search for files as well as content.  I also like the fact that you can run it on demand as it does not use an invasive, indexing service.
[Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is not exactly a lightweight solution, but I have to recommend it.  It's come a long way towards becoming an excellent JavaScript editor.

Visual Studio's IntelliSense is able to infer JavaScript types and give you a dropdown of the functions and values in your object (works pretty well).

Of course, I always have my handy little muscle memory spasm: double-click-select -> Ctrl-C -> Ctrl-Shift-F -> Ctrl-V -> ENTER

And here's a plugin that pre-searches for exact string matches in your entire solution and highlights them for you, so jumping to a function definition is instantaneous.  [Whole Tomato's Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/)